# Select data from three tables including null

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 3 tables:

```
1. tbl_Country(CountryID,CountryName)
2. tbl_Customer(CustumerID,Name,CountryID,StateID)
3. tbl_State(StateID,StateName,CountryID)
```

I am trying to join these tables using the query below:

```
select cu.CustID,
       cu.CountryID,
       cu.StateID,
       cu.Name,
       c.CountryName,
       s.StateName 
from tbl_Customer cu, 
     tbl_Country c,
     tbl_State s 
where c.CountryID = cu.CountryID and 
       s.StateID = cu.StateID and 
       c.CountryID = s.CountryID
```

But I can not fetch customers who didn't specify a country name or a state name. I don't know how to write full outer join query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use left joins. If customer is your main table, start your query from that one.

```
SELECT cu.CustID, 
       cu.CountryID, 
       cu.StateID, 
       cu.Name, 
       c.CountryName, 
       s.StateName 
FROM   tbl_Customer cu 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_Country c 
              ON cu.CountryId = c.CountryId 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_State s 
              ON s.StateID = cu.StateID 
                 AND c.CountryID = s.CountryID
```

Answer (score 4):

use explicit join

```
  select cu.CustID,
           cu.CountryID,
           cu.StateID,
           cu.Name,
           c.CountryName,
           s.StateName  
    from tbl_Customer cu left join
         tbl_Country c on   c.CountryID = cu.CountryID
         left join tbl_State s   s.StateID = cu.StateID
         and c.CountryID = s.CountryID
```